# Microsoft authentication in ASP.NET Core - MFA

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We are implementing our own Federated authentication server using ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer 4, and have successfully implemented the Microsoft account version first.

Once the user has authenticated through Microsoft, is there a way to know whether MFA was applied during their authentication process? I know I can implement MFA specifically in the IdentityServer itself, but I don't want to have the user run through multiple MFA cycles unnecessarily.

The same question would apply for any external provider (Google, Facebook, etc), but I'll deal with Microsoft for now.

Comment: You can check the issuer in the claim to know the identity provider. Also, AuthenticationScheme should also be specifying the authentication provider name.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about personal MS account authentication. If this used Azure AD, there would be an acr claim that contains "mfa" if the user went through MFA.

Comment: As above, look for `acr` or `amr` claims that should indicate what method(s) were used to authenticate the user.